# Wrapping text over a dropped caps symbol

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I've got a problem with an HTML/CSS page I'm working on. It has a few numbered paragraphs with the text overlapping the 'dot' symbol on the last line of text. You can see more precisely what I'm referring on the picture below. It will be a static page, but I would love a solution which doesn't require fixed position.

[image: Pic1]

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdoDO.png) - This is what I need to achieve.

The problem I'm facing is, I believe, due to the height the dot symbol takes when I give it a big font size, and I end up with this

[image: Pic2]

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLQRb.png) - This is where I was able to get to.

EDIT: I'm including the HTML and CSS files below.

Code:

```css
    .mainText{
        font-size: 1.5em;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .dropCapOne, .dropCapDot{
        font-size: 230px;
        float: left;
    }
    .dropCapOne {
        letter-spacing: -60px;
    }
    .restOfText{
        margin-top: 70px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
        <div class="mainText mainTextFirst">
            <span class="dropCapOne">1</span>
            <span class="dropCapDot">.</span>
            <span class="restOfText">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Quisque sed libero gravida, condimentum nisi ut, tristique justo. 
                Nullam erat urna, sollicitudin
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Pictures are fine, but we need to see some CSS and HTML!

Comment: a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) link with your html/css code would be great

Comment: Or just include a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/215552) so that we don't depend on JSfiddle...

Comment: Getting the necessary space at the beginning of the 5th line of text is going to be the major problem here - and not one you are going to achieve easily with CSS, unless you'd be willing to give CSS Shapes a go, but in addition to rather poor browser support (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes) I'm afraid that's not going to work very well for dynamic numbers either. Before CSS shapes people used to achieve similar effects to get text aligned to a semi-circle or other curve using a couple of floated and also cleared elements of different widths, maybe that could be a way to go here ...

Comment: I would of for sure rejected this design from the start

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, it's just a lot of hassle

The main issue is have the text to wrap above the dot, in this case(my fiddle), a red square, I am sure you can work out the dot to replace the red square (border-radius if you have to).

I moved the dot into the text span (you can try moving it out now that you know the concept of achieving this). I added a spacer(float) above the dot so we can push the dot down to the proper location, clearing left for the dot and you have what you need

https://jsfiddle.net/nyen7p0x/2/

Dot using border radius - https://jsfiddle.net/nyen7p0x/3/

CSS

```
.dropCapDot{
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background: red;
   overflow: hidden;
   clear: left;
}
.dropSpacer {
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  height: 108px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="mainContent">
  <div class="mainText mainTextFirst">
    <span class="dropCapOne">1</span>

    <span class="restOfText">
                <span class="dropSpacer"></span>
    <span class="dropCapDot">.</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed libero gravida, condimentum nisi ut, tristique justo. Nullam erat urna, sollicitudin
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would of still rejected the design from the start though